# Alert dialog not functioning correctly.

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog

This code I am working on requires the user to press a button after entering a phone number into a text box. The button is made to save the number.

When I run the code I want to have it present the user with an alert dialog asking them to enter a number if they pressed the button with no number present.

Instead of getting the alert dialog the app crashes. But with a number entered the app works just fine.

Any advice on this would be awesome - Here is the code with the stack trace under that.
-Thank you!

```
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Create an if statement that brings up an alert dialog if there is no number entered into the field.
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnwidgetconfig: {
                if (sharedData == null)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
                    alert.setTitle("No number entered");
                    alert.setMessage("Please enter a phone number using the the text box");
                    alert.setCancelable(false);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                                    0);
                        }
                    });


                }
                else
                {
                String stringData = sharedData.getText().toString();
                Long l = Long.parseLong(stringData);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                prefs.edit().putLong(constants.KEY, l).commit();
                Toast.makeText(c, "Your number has been saved!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                svNum.setText("Saved Number: " + prefs.getLong(constants.KEY, 411));
                break;
                }
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

////Stack Trace:

```
05-14 12:29:07.679: W/dalvikvm(30842): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x40018560)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:337)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:311)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at example.save.phonenum.Settings$1.onClick(WWSettings.java:106)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
05-14 12:29:07.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30842):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 12:29:15.569: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30870): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: First, you need to call `alert.show();` to get your dialog to appear. Second, I think your error has to do with the variable sharedData. Where is the code for that var?

Comment: @TronicZomB the OP must have that somewhere, we just don't see it because it works when a number is entered. The problem is trying to parse an empty `String`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this `sharedData` is a `TextView`. Which you are still trying to parse the result when it is null, hence the NFE. Put in a check to only run that code if there is a valid number. You are checking if it is `null`, which the `TextView` may not be but the contents are an empty `String` which you are trying to `parse`

Change

```
if (sharedData == null)
```

to something like

```
if (sharedData == null || sharedData.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    ...
```

I would try to get the text before that line into your `stringData` variable then check if that is empty. Also, you will want to put a `try/catch` around the parsing code in case they try to enter a non-digit and display a message, unless you've already done that

Comment: Aye, its an edit Text not a text view. Also the code is setup in the ET to only accept numeric input (Number pad instead of keyboard)

Comment: `EditText` is what I meant, sorry, but either way that's your problem. You're trying to parse an empty `String`

Comment: If you are only allowing numbers then you may not need it but still not a bad practice to get used to. But you would put the parsing inside the `try` and `catch` `NumberFormatException`. But the underlying problem here is that you aren't checking if the contents of your `EditText` are empty as in my answer. You are only checking if the `EditText` is `null`

Comment: Alright implemented your code change. Still spitting out errors. Let me see if its anything new. -- Nope still the same.

Comment: I edited the `if` statement in my answer...I screwed up, sorry. Check that

Comment: Your code logically makes sense, but for some reason its not working the way it was intended to. Even after code change.

Comment: Are you getting the same error or a different one? I don't see how you could be getting the same one

Comment: change `Long l` to `long l`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29933/discussion-between-codemagic-and-codemonkeyalx)